# reverse definition for magic square

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

Recently, I saw a question in [see here](http://www.puzzling.stackexchange.com) which is so interesting for me. This question is as follows:

> Is it possible to fill the $121$ entries in an $11×11$ square with the values $0,+1,−1$, so that the row sums and column sums are $22$ distinct numbers?

This problem is interesting for me because its definition is reverse of the magic square. I think for solve this problem we must use something like design theory. Also, for $n=6$ this problem have an answer. My next question is:

> For which integer number $n$, this problem has a solution and is this problem well known in math?

I will be so thankful for any helpful comments and answers.

Comment: You should note that if there is an answer, there is one with a row sum of 11 and a row sum of -11. (Why?)  Can you use this to figure out what other row and column sums there must be?  Gerhard "Can Work With Ternary Matrices" Paseman, 2016.01.15.

Comment: @Meysam: can you say how you obtained the answer for $n=6$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is so famous. For first trivial reference, you can see:[link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/-101-Matrix.html).

$\it{R. Bodendiek}$ and $\it{G. Burosch}$ studied this problem in a paper with name:

"Solution to the Antimagic 0,1,-1 Matrix Problem."

If there is solution for integer $n$, then we have:

$1)$ $n$ is even,

$2)$ The number in $\{-n,1-n,2-n,...,n\}$ that does not appear as a line sum is either $-n$ or $n$,

$3)$ Of the $n$ largest line sums, half are column sums and half are row sums.

Also, you can search about "Alternating sum matrix", for more information.

Comment: What is the connection between antimagic matrix and alternating sign matrix? Searching for "alternating sum matrix" is not giving any obvious leads towards antimagic matrix problem.

Comment: @Scipi: I pointed it out since if you see "CRC Handbook of mathematics-2ed", after introducing this subject, it gives some keywords for more research about similar problems. In some texts, when they talk about similar problems, they also talk about antimagic matrix problem.